# Open Source Alternatives to MS Teams

Tags: software-rec, skype, chat, voice, jitsi-meet

In the presence of current wave of COVID-19, we all are forced to work-from-home and attend online group meetings. In this context, my organization is currently using MS Teams for such meetings. However, we are trying to move away to some other similar product (as we are not comfortable to give control and data to MS). So, in this effort, first we tried Zoom, but it has a limitation of 40 minutes. Then we tried Jitsi, which is good but in  Jitsi, anyone of the participants can kick-out any other (which is a serious problem). Therefore, we are still looking for an Open Source alternative to MS Teams at least following functionalities:

> 1. Confrence Call
> 2. Screen Sharing
> 3. Only Admin can kick out any member

If you happen to know any software with these features, kindly let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered the jitsi moderator plugin? [here](https://github.com/nvonahsen/jitsi-token-moderation-plugin)

Comment: No. I searched for some jitsi options, but it seems that in order to get extra functionality, I need personal domain. Which I don't have. Actually this is me who is trying to motivate people in my organization to move to Open Source, that's why I have to confirm things on my own end first.

Comment: This should be asked [over on softwarerecs.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Also, I think you are trying to fix a social problem by technical means. It _can_ be done, but it makes more sense - IMO - to create an atmosphere where people don't kick each other out. So unless we're talking about children ages 1..12, I think one can expect to solve this without resorting to technical means.

Comment: Sometimes, people beyond 12 years of age act like kids :-(

Comment: How does this relate Linux/Unix? The OP wants a "serverless" solution. I'm voting to migrate the question to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Zoom does not have a 40 minute limit if you pay for it.  I often use Zoom for 10+ hours a day.  If you are looking for a free serverless conferencing system, you should state that requirement in your question.

Comment: Folks, software requests are on topic here, as long as the software runs on *nix systems.

Comment: @terdon thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with Jitsi if you install your own server and do the "Secure Domain setup": https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/secure-domain

Once you have a secure domain setup, only authenticated users are allowed to create new conference rooms. On creating the room the host becomes a moderator and the guests will not be moderators (everyone is a moderator on meet.jit.si) and only the moderator can kick out other participants.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. In the page you linked, I did not find a mention of how this will prevent normal participants from kicking out other participants; could you edit your answer to clarify how your proposed solution will do that (as it seems to be one of the primary challenges the OP faces)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Big Blue Button https://bigbluebutton.org/ 
Satisfies all your requirements, but you need to install this on your own server.

Comment: I am looking for serverless options. Reason mentioned above. Also, Welcome to Stack Exchange :-)

Comment: @SalmanAhmed whoa, you might want to actually mention this in your question. Also, how do you come to think that Jitsi Meet is _serverless_?! I can tell you from the experience of setting up and running a Jitsi Meet server, that it's very much "serverful" 

Comment: @SalmanAhmed.  All the video conferencing systems I have used over the years, including Zoom, are server-based.

Comment: I think I misunderstood. By serverless, I mean, in order to create the setup, I don't have to create Server or own a domain.